# How to specify one attribute of a model inside a collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

```
render: function () {
    news.fetchMyNews();

    for (var i = 1; i <= news.length; i++) {
        var newsData = news.get(i);
        var newsRow = JST["news/row"](newsData.attributes);
        $("#news_tbody").append(newsRow);
        if (newsData.is_read == 1) {
            this.$('tr').attr("class", "news_read");
        } else if (newsData.is_read == 0) {
            this.$('tr').attr("class", "news_unread");
        }
    }
}
```

In this code newsData.attributes is retrieved well and I get the table with 3 rows rendered.

However, the newsData.is_read values are not retrieved and there is no error message at all, thus, the rows don't get styling.

news is a collection.

I wonder, what can be wrong with this?
JSON file that I'm using for testing looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "_type": "friends",
    "message": "Your friend ...",
    "is_read": 1
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "_type": "friends",
    "message": "Your friend ...",
    "is_read": 0
},

{
    "id": 3,
    "_type": "other",
    "message": "User ...",
    "is_read": 1
}]
```

Comment: Isn't that `fetchMyNews` method asynchronous?

Comment: @undefined
fetchMyNews: function() {
   this.fetch({async:false});
  }

Comment: Have you logged to `newsData` to the console to see what it returns? Have you tried `newsData.get('is_read')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `newsData` is a Model for getting it's attributes either `.get('is_read')` or `newsData.attributes.is_read` should be used.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I suspected that it's something easy! :)

Comment: @ArmanOspanov You are welcome :), just a note, for iterating through the collections you can also use `.each()` method instead of the `for` loop, Backbone collections inherit the method from Underscore. `news.each(fn)` will work.